# function hashing/fingerprinting as a built-in feature?

Tags: function, haskell, hash, lisp

How can one get a stable hash of a function at runtime?

This means the hash changes if the implementation changes, and this is recursive, so if there is a nested function call, the nested function hash will affect the outer function hash.

Not sure which language has this feature. I'm looking for a practical programming language where it is trivial and performant.

I guess functional languages, perhaps lisp or haskell are the usual suspects, but unsure how this looks like.

```
function myFunction() {
    ... // Some code, possibly using names from other files/modules/libraries
}

 // Prints the hash which changes if anything in the implementation of `myFunction` changes, stable across runs.
print(hash(myFunction))
```

is there such a language? if so an example of how this is written and why it works is desired.

non-examples would be js, python, java...

Comment: This sounds almost exactly like Unison: https://www.unisonweb.org/docs/tour/

Comment: That would break one the main guarantees of Haskell, referential transparency, so that's also out. Very roughly put in Haskell you are not supposed to be able to distinguish `f x = 1+x` from, say, `f x = x+1` -- you can only call a function, not inspect its code, not even through an hash.

Comment: This is not achievable in any language with higher-order functions I think: `(define (foo f o) (f o o))` for instance: there is no way of knowing statically what function `foo` calls.

Comment: The GHC compiler for Haskell hashes *modules* to figure out what it might need to recompile. But to the best of my knowledge it doesn't do anything like that for individual functions. What do you want this feature for?

Comment: @dfeuer I recommend watching the unison videos, they explain the benefits pretty well. Among other things I wanted it to persistently cache results safely.

Comment: @tfb evidently it can be done, check out the unison videos.

Comment: @Uri: it can't in any language with higher-order functions.  There simply *is no way* of knowing what function a function whose definition is `(lambda (f a) (f a))` calls, because that function is a parameter.

Comment: Your syntax isn't very clear to me, can you write it imperative style? Also unison has higher order functions (it is similar to haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a general-purpose programming language, Unison does exactly this pervasively:

> Each Unison definition is some syntax tree, and by hashing this tree in a way that incorporates the hashes of all that definition's dependencies, we obtain the Unison hash which uniquely identifies that definition.
>
> — https://www.unisonweb.org/docs/tour

Every Unison definition is identified by a [512-bit SHA3 hash](https://www.unisonweb.org/docs/faq), and is immutable—you cannot modify a definition, only create a new one. Moreover, *names* are stored separately from definitions, so renaming is a trivial operation, and if two people write *structurally* the same code with only different variable & function names, their code will share the same hash and thus be identified as the same code.

As for configuration languages, Dhall does as well:

> Use Dhall's support for semantic hashes to guarantee that many types of refactors are behavior-preserving
>
> — https://dhall-lang.org/

Since Dhall is non–Turing complete, every expression has a *normal form*,  and the hash of this normal form can be used to identify it, so when you refactor your Dhall code, you can have strong assurance that it produces identical results.

Comment: unison is exactly what I'm after thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this in a commercial application written in Common Lisp, deployed using CCL (Clozure Common Lisp).

You can do it by obtaining a represenation of the compiled image of the function using `disassemble`, and then hashing that using as suitable digester, like the one in Ironclad.

What I actually used in the CCL solution was the functions `ccl::%function-code-words` to obtain how many words there are in the function and the accessor `ccl::%function-code-byte` to get at the bytes (there are four times as many as the number of words).

Obviously, a hash based on the code bytes will not reflect differences in captured lexical environment between instances of functions created at the same point in the program at different times.

The implementation wasn't recursive. Rather, the overall solution iterated over a known list of functions.